# Why same SQL query has different behavior(according with syntax) in UNIX shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

Why the following query have different behavior according with syntax

**SYNTAX 1**

```
sqlplus -silent $conn <<EOF
select 'aman' from dual;
EXIT;
EOF
```

**SYNTAX 2**

```
resultset2=`sqlplus -silent $conn <<EOF
select 'aman' from dual;
EXIT;
EOF 
`
```

**SYNTAX 3**

```
resultset2=$(sqlplus -silent  $conn<<EOF
select 'aman' from dual;
EXIT;
EOF
)
```

Syntax 1 and 2 are working fine but syntax 3 gives me error

```
ORA-00904: "aman": invalid identifier
```

Comment: @RC. please explain why the syntax 3 gives me error?

Comment: It doesn't, unless your particular shell is doing something very weird. You'd only see that error if you'd used double quotes instead of single quotes in the third example. Are these all exact cut-and-paste from your actual shell scripts, or have you retyped them, or edited them?

Comment: @AlexPoole they are copy-and-pasted from script and there is one more point that when i enable shell log(set -x) then i see that my shell is converting 'aman' to "aman"

Comment: OK, then which shell and version are you using?

Comment: @AlexPoole Shell is Ksh and version sorry i don't know

Comment: version mayb Ultrix 4.0, 4.5

Comment: Looks like a ksh88 issue then; you can verify with `ksh --version`. Two workarounds in the duplicate question; or use a different shell (or version); or use the syntax2 approach with backticks, of course.